# Как добавить значки(картинки) в проект Python на tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

Создал нужный значок, добавил в папку с проектом. В самом редакторе файл отражается и открывается, но в программу не подтягивается

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file= 'f.png')
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.config(bg='#007373')
win.title('мое приложение')
win.geometry('500x500+100+200')


win.mainloop()
```

вот такая ошибка:

```
PS G:\PYTHON> & C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe g:/PYTHON/.vscode/project/123.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\PYTHON\.vscode\project\123.py", line 3, in <module>
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file= 'f.png')
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "f.png": no such file or directory
PS G:\PYTHON>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно смотреть структуру проекта, как запускаете, где значки лежат. Если все в корне проекта лежит, и вы в vscode открываете проект как папку, а не отдельный файл .py, то вообще проблем никаких не должно быть. Если все разложено по папкам, то нужно видеть где что лежит.

Comment: В корневой папке vscode, создана папка с проектом, в ней файл python  и png значок. Добавил скрин

Comment: У вас сейчас корень проекта - папка `G:/PYTHON`. Он же считается текущей папкой. Все пути отсчитываются от этой папки (т.е. значок ищется в папке G:/python, а не в папке со скриптом). Нужно либо в vscode через "открыть папку" открыть папку project, и так с проектом и работать, либо прописать путь к значку относительно папки PYTHON, т.е. `project/f.png` вместо просто `f.png`. Еще есть третий вариант: в скрипте определять папку, где лежит ваш скрипт, и указать путь явно от этой папки.

Comment: Благодарю за совет!

Answer (score 0):

По скриншоту видно, что у вас как корень проекта в vscode открыта папка `G:/PYTHON`, она же в данном случае текущая папка. Из-за этого файл f.png ищется в ней.

Варианты решения:

1. Открыть в vscode как проект папку `G:/PYTHON/project`
2. Указывать путь относительно папки `G:/PYTHON`, т.е. `photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='project/f.png')`
3. Программно определить папку, в которой лежит сам файл скрипта `123.py`, указать путь относительно этой папки:

```
import tkinter as tk

from pathlib import Path

script_directory = Path(__file__).parent

win = tk.Tk()
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=script_directory / 'f.png')
win.iconphoto(False, photo)
win.config(bg='#007373')
win.title('мое приложение')
win.geometry('500x500+100+200')
win.mainloop()
```